# Consulta horizontal en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql, subconsultas

Buen dia Estimados.
Necesito ayuda en como hacer para que mi consulta sea horizontal: muestro el query el cual me retorna un monto por cada consulta, pero deseo obtenerlo en una cola consulta y por columnas horizontales.

`select top 1 MAX(Monto) Monto1 from Tbl_Abono where CapacidadPago < 70 and PlazoId = 1
select top 1 MAX(Monto) Monto2 from Tbl_Abono where CapacidadPago < 70 and PlazoId = 2
select top 1 MAX(Monto) Monto3 from Tbl_Abono where CapacidadPago < 70 and PlazoId = 3
select top 1 MAX(Monto) Monto4 from Tbl_Abono where CapacidadPago < 70 and PlazoId = 4
select top 1 MAX(Monto) Monto5 from Tbl_Abono where CapacidadPago < 70 and PlazoId = 5`

El resultado que deseo obtener es el siguiente.

`|CapacidadPago | Monto1 | Monto2 | Monto3 | Monto4 | Monto5
---------------|------- |------- |------- |------- |-------
|70            | 3250   | 4200   | 1500   | 2800   | 500`

De antemano Muchas Gracias.

Comment: La respuesta es realizar [CASE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp)

Comment: Por favor, no compartas consultas y datos como imagen. Replicar tu problema se hace muy dispendioso y se lo haces difícil a los que leemos desde móvil o a los que tienen alguna discapacidad. Así mismo, evita usar mayúsculas sostenidas. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Otra opción, aparte de resolverlo con CASE, es usar una variable de tipo tabla, e ir insertando los valores en columnas:

```
declare @tabla table (capacidadPago int, monto1 int, monto2 int, monto3 int, monto4 int , monto5 int)
insert into @tabla (capacidadPago) values (70)

update @tabla set monto1 = (select top 1 MAX(Monto) Monto1 from Tbl_Abono where CapacidadPago < 70 and PlazoId = 1) where capacidadPago = 70
update @tabla set monto2 = (select top 1 MAX(Monto) Monto1 from Tbl_Abono where CapacidadPago < 70 and PlazoId = 2) where capacidadPago = 70
update @tabla set monto3 = (select top 1 MAX(Monto) Monto1 from Tbl_Abono where CapacidadPago < 70 and PlazoId = 3) where capacidadPago = 70
update @tabla set monto4 = (select top 1 MAX(Monto) Monto1 from Tbl_Abono where CapacidadPago < 70 and PlazoId = 4) where capacidadPago = 70
update @tabla set monto5 = (select top 1 MAX(Monto) Monto1 from Tbl_Abono where CapacidadPago < 70 and PlazoId = 5) where capacidadPago = 70

select * from @tabla
```

Comment: Esto me funciona, quisiera saber para que sirve el @tabla , y si es una tabla temporal se elimina para poder reutilizarlo. Muchas Gracias Estimado.

Comment: La variable @table, es una tabla en memoria, a diferencia de las tablas temporales no utiliza tempdb, no es necesario destruirla después de usarla, y no persiste a través de distintos contextos (no podes declararla en un SP, y consultarla en otro), tampoco se le pueden declarar índices. Es bastante práctica para conjuntos de datos pequeños.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro si la columna de Capacidad de pago es un dato fijo o un valor de la columna en la tabla del mismo nombre. En el primer caso, es imposible lograr ese resultado con la condición puesta en el WHERE.

De cualquier forma, puedes hacer un agregado condicional para obtener los resultados en multiples columnas y una sola fila.

```
SELECT  70 AS CapacidadPago,
        MAX( CapacidadPago) AS CapacidadPago,
        MAX( CASE WHEN PlazoId = 1 THEN Monto) AS Monto1,
        MAX( CASE WHEN PlazoId = 1 THEN Monto) AS Monto2,
        MAX( CASE WHEN PlazoId = 1 THEN Monto) AS Monto3,
        MAX( CASE WHEN PlazoId = 1 THEN Monto) AS Monto4
FROM Tbl_Abono
WHERE CapacidadPago < 70;
```